# What is log4j bridge for migration?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm planning to migrate an application from Log4j 1.x to Log4j 2.y. I'm reading up on the [migration strategies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) and the frist option that is provided is the use of a bridge. I don't understand what is meant by a bridge and how the whole thing is supposed to work. If they are referring to the [brdige pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/bridge), then I don't see how it applies in that case.

As far as I understood is that I keep my code untouched and my Log4j Jars untouched and add the Log4j 2 jars and the Log4j bridge jar file. This sounds like a very simple solution but I'm automatically drawn to the second option (chaning some code snippets and the imports for each class that uses Log4j and switching the Jar from v1 to v2). Yet I feel like I haven't understood the option 1 and not considered the pros and cons of it. Does anybody have some insight on this?

Answer (score 2):

From the description in the [migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) you reference, option one does pretty much what you think it does - it lets you keep using the Log4j 1.x API in your code, while using the Log4j 2.x implementation to do the actual logging. Feels more like an *adapter* pattern to me.

The migration guide discusses some limitations, but if you use the logging API in the most common way, it should not make any difference.

Option two requires code changes, so it depends on the size of your code base and willingness to do the migration all at once (instead of, say, migrating the files gradually when you make changes to them).